# Captions are not justified once \usepackage{subcaption} is included

Tags: pdftex, captions, subcaption, overleaf

I have the following problem:
if I use package \usepackage{subcaption} to construct subfigures, my caption under the figure* becomes not justified. To demonstrate this problem I use "RevTeX 4.2 Template and Sample" from Overleaf:

```
\documentclass[amsmath,amssymb, aps]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files

\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point

\usepackage{bm}% bold math

\usepackage[format=plain, justification=justified]{subcaption}
```

.
.
.

```
\begin{figure*}

\includegraphics{fig_2}\caption{...Long not justified caption...}

\end{figure*}
```

.
.
.

The Result 1:

[image]

The caption is justified, if I do not use \usepackage{subcaption}.
Here is the Result 2:

[image]

I want my caption to be as in Result 2 but with included \usepackage{subcaption}. I would be happy to get any help!
Thank You in advance!

Comment: `revtex` and `caption` don't go along. But you can use `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` (it has a different syntax), so `revtex` caption are not touched.

Answer (score 3):

You get a warning

```latex
Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package),
(caption)                standard defaults will be used.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

This means that `caption` will revert the caption commands to something it knows which is definitely not what `revtex4-2` expects.

Following John Kormylo's advice, but adding `\show\caption` (for debugging) after `\begin{document}` issues

```latex
> \caption=macro:
->\minipagefootnote@here \caption@iftype {\caption@checkgrouplevel \@empty \cap
tion \caption@star {\caption@refstepcounter \@captype }{\caption@dblarg {\@capt
ion \@captype }}}{\caption@Error {\noexpand \caption outside float}\caption@gob
ble }.
```

whereas the original definition of the class is

```latex
> \caption=macro:
->\minipagefootnote@here \ifx \@captype \@undefined \@latex@error {\noexpand \c
aption outside float}\@ehd \expandafter \@gobble \else \refstepcounter \@captyp
e \expandafter \@firstofone \fi {\@dblarg {\@caption \@captype }}.
```

So it's not just a question of saving and restoring `\@makecaption`.

If you want to live dangerously and risk your submission is rejected…

Otherwise, use `subfig`, which *is* compatible with `revtex4-2`.

```latex
\documentclass[amsmath,amssymb, aps]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\subfloat[A subcaption\label{A}]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}\quad
\subfloat[A subcaption\label{B}]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}

\bigskip

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\caption{...Long not justified caption...
...Long not justified caption...
...Long not justified caption...
...Long not justified caption...
...Long not justified caption...
...Long not justified caption...
...Long not justified caption...
...Long not justified caption...
...Long not justified caption...\label{C}}
\end{figure*}

\ref{A}, \ref{B}, \ref{C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear egreg,

Thank you very much! Everything works fine!

Answer (score 1):

This restores the original `\@makecaption`.  This also disables any formatting applied by the caption or subcaption packages.

```
\documentclass[amsmath,amssymb, aps]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\makeatletter
\let\old@makecaption=\@makecaption
\usepackage{subcaption}
\let\@makecaption=\old@makecaption
\makeatother
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{\blindtext}% justified
\subcaption{\blindtext}% centered
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```