# How to remove centering of the captions in figures and subfigures?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, ragged2e

I am facing trouble removing centering of the captions in the figures, I tried `justification==justified` as well, but its not working. Also, I tried `\raggedright` in the caption, it is moving the caption to the left margin, but it is not justified (hyphens are not coming). I tried `\usepackage{ragged2e}` and `\RaggedRight` as well, nothing is working. I am using `preprint` in the document class.

```
\documentclass[preprint,pre,amsmath]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,justification=justified]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
 \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{plot1.png}
     %\caption{}
     \label{figa}
 \end{subfigure}
 %\hfill
 \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{plot2.png}
    %\caption{}
    \label{figb}
 \end{subfigure}
% \hfill
 \caption{\raggedright Solar atmosphere temperature-height distribution.Solar atmosphere temperature-height distribution as determined by \cite{15}. Height is given in kilometers measured above zero point where $\tau=1$. Regions of line formation are also indicated. From right to left: photosphere, temperature minimum (4,000K), chromosphere, transition region (8,500K) and Lyman valley (20,000K).}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In your example you're putting the figures inside the preamble resp. don't define a document body using `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. This way it cannot work. And in the last main caption you're using a wrong opening brace, it has to be a bracket. Plus that optional argument defines only the short caption for the LoF not the main caption printed below the figure itself.

Comment: Sorry, those were typos. Please check it now.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551588/captions-are-not-justified-once-usepackagesubcaption-is-included. Documentc class `revtex4-2` is not compatible with `caption` and `subcaption` packages, consequently it overwrite their settings. If you write article for journal which use `revtex` document class please obey their rules and don't try to change them.

Comment: okay, thankyou so much for your suggestion.